# Crystal reports does not identify System.DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, crystal-reports, dataset

I am coding in C# and I use *Crystal Reports* in my application.
I have to use a custom query (handwritten) for the report so I use a `DataSet.xsd`.
In that dataset I have a `DateTime` field, so I made the type of the `DateTime` field to `System.DateTime`.

In my report I m using a parameter to check the date, but the *Crystal Reports* does not identify that `DateTime` field in the dataset as a `DateTime`.

I have set the parameter value type to `DateTime` too.

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: @v4vendetta: It s the Crystal reports that comes with Visual Studio 2005. I don t know the version exactly... thanks

Comment: I'll check on this tomorrow and try to answer in the morning if no one else has.  Only commenting so I can find the question again.

Comment: @lazyDBA: Thanks a lot!!! I solved the problem in another way, that is instead of using report parameters, I filtered my data using the handwritten query itself and then filled the dataset. That solved my problem, but actually it s not an answer to this particular question. If you can find any solution, please post it here... So much appreciated on your comment... Thank you...